# Does Marketing Cloud SQL support WITH?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am trying to run this query:

```
WITH Visibilities (A__c, B__c, C__c, D__c) AS
(SELECT A__c, B__c, C__c, D__c
 FROM ent.Brand_Category_Visibility__c_Salesforce
 WHERE Brand__c = 'Some brand'
 AND Category__c = 'Some cat'
)
SELECT A__c
FROM Visibilities
WHERE A__c IS NOT NULL
AND D__c = 0
```

But I am getting a generic error: Unable to create temporary data extension: Field name cannot be blank.

The [Salesforce reference on this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5) does not mention WITH, so I don't know if it is supported or not (but I am beginning to suspect it is not).

Comment: is this error in the query activity or query studio?

Comment: @EazyE Query Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to save the above query within Automation studio / query activity you would get this error

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Only SELECT queries are valid. Select must be the first word of the query. Visibilities is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

Comment: Thanks, I always try my queries first in Query Studio before passing them on to Automation Studio. In this case AS has the better error message. Although technically not correct, because formally speaking WITH is a part of a SELECT query.

Comment: WITH is affecting a 'level' above SELECT - this means that although it is related and utilized by SELECT, it is not possible in SFMC because SFMC SQL is limited to SELECT queries 'levels' and below. This is because SFMC wraps its own SQL around your Query so it limits your capabilities of SQL usage to prevent any syntax or misinterpretations with those wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

SFMC will only accept SELECT statements, which means WITH will not work as it exists outside the SELECT query. You can find this in the official docs **[here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)**

> Only SELECT statements to data extension or data views in an account or in the parent account

Comment: I already mentioned the official docs in my question. It refers to SQL Server 2016, which supports WITH. The documentation does not mention WITH explicitly, which makes it ambiguous whether it is supported or not.

Comment: @sanderdejong - It says only SELECT statements are possible - meaning it will accept nothing that does not being with SELECT. Which is the quote I pulled above. Not sure how much more explicit you need it to be...