# How to parameterize a Marketing Cloud SQL query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a single, long and complex query, nested and all, using various UNIONs and EXCEPTs. In several WHERE clauses fields are compared to literal strings and some of these literal strings are used in more than one WHERE clause.

From a viewpoint of maintenance and readability, I would like to have these literal values defined close together and each value only once. A solution for that would be to use the SQL keyword WITH, but alas, [MC SQL does not support that](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/364292/does-marketing-cloud-sql-support-with). I have also googled for using parameters or variables, but so far it seems like MC SQL does not support that either.

You may say that my database is not properly normalized, but

1. These UNIONs and EXCEPTs are all on the same table.
2. The database is a given thing, it cannot be changed.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE Attr_A = 'literal string 1'
AND Attr_B = 'literal string 2'
AND ...
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE Attr_A = 'literal string 1'
AND Attr_B = 'literal string 2'
AND ...
EXCEPT
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE Attr_A = 'literal string 1'
AND Attr_B = 'literal string 2'
AND ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using WITH (which is not supported in SFMC as you said) depending on your query complication, you can try using only common where clauses within the outer query after you applied all UNIONs. Something like this:

```
SELECT  Attr_A, Attr_B, Attr_C
FROM     
(   SELECT Attr_A, Attr_B, Attr_C
    FROM ...
    UNION
    SELECT Attr_D, Attr_E, Attr_F
    FROM ...
)
WHERE Attr_A = 'literal string 1'
AND Attr_B = 'literal string 2'
```

If it's going to take more time to run the query, I'd suggest first run your initial query and create another SQL query step by pointing out only common where clauses.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, though I suspect that it will take longer, as the used WHERE clauses eliminate many records (and I believe it is good practice to eliminate as many records as early as possible). Multi query steps is also an option, but I would prefer a single query, from the viewpoint of maintainability.